# Using tfcompile to AOT Compile Tensorflow Graph for iOS

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to use [tfcompile](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/performance/xla/tfcompile) to AOT compile a Tensorflow graph to run on iOS? This will presumably require cross-compiling. If so, how do I set `tfcompile` to compile the graph for iOS?